# Error al mostrar div con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, validación, jquery-validate

Comenze a usar bootstrap y me di cuenta de que se utiliza JQuery,y empeze a programar un poco con esta librería el tema en cuestión esque no funciona una validación que reilase.

```
<form  method="post" id="ingresar" >
             <input name="nombre" type="text"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
             <div id="mnom" class="errores"  >El nombre no es valido</div>
             <button type="submit" name="insertar" id="btn-insert">Insertar</button>
</form>
```

Este es el formulario que deseo validar por el momento quiero validar que solo se ingresen letras y que no este vacio

```
 <script>
    var numeros = /^[0-9]+$/;
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#btn-insert").click(function(e) {
        var nombre= $("#nombre").val();

        if(nombre == "" || numeros.test(nombre)){
            $("#mnom").fadeIn();
            return false;
        }else{
            $("#mnom").fadeOut();
            }
    });
});
```

La validación no funciona el formulario me envía lo datos igual y no me muestra el div con id= mnom

Answer (score 1):

La validación de hace en el `onsubmit` del formulario, de modo que si devuelve false no se envía.

```
<form  method="post" id="ingresar" onsubmit="return Comprobar();">
   <input name="nombre" type="text"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" />
   <div id="mnom" class="errores"  >El nombre no es valido</div>
   <button type="submit" name="insertar" id="btn-insert">Insertar</button>
</form>

<script>
function Comprobar (){
   var numeros = /^[0-9]+$/;
   var nombre= $("#nombre").val();

   if(nombre == "" || numeros.test(nombre)){
      $("#mnom").fadeIn();
      return false;
   } else {
      $("#mnom").fadeOut();
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esa fue la solución!!

Comment: No hay de que :), en ese caso márcala como contestada para que no quede sin responder.